# Why is my Promise in pending status ? HTTP requests library was changed

Tags: node.js, promise

I changed from deprecated request to axios. The [original code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/narenaryan/e1c9ed3f8ba08b82b1ae7dd2b9009db8/raw/52adf62095642a566b33e27954d615aaa16beba1/main.js)

My code

```
var axios = require("axios");
var userDetails;

function initialize() {
    const url = "https://api.github.com/users/narenaryan"
    var options = {


    headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'axios'
        }
    };
    // Return new promise 
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // Do async job
        axios.get(url, options, function(err, resp, body) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(JSON.parse(body));
            }
        })
    })

}

function main() {
    var initializePromise = initialize();
    console.log(initializePromise);
    initializePromise.then(function(result) {
        userDetails = result;
        console.log("Initialized user details");
        // Use user details from here
        console.log(userDetails)
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    })
}

main();
```

When I run it

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of axios.get didn't accept callback function it returns a promise use the below code it will work.

```
    var axios = require("axios");
    var userDetails;

    function initialize() {
        const url = "https://api.github.com/users/narenaryan"
        var options = {
            headers: {
                'User-Agent': 'axios'
            }
        };
        console.log(url, options)
        return axios.get(url, options);
    }

    function main() {
        var initializePromise = initialize();
        console.log(initializePromise);
        initializePromise.then(function (result) {
            userDetails = result;
            console.log("Initialized user details");
            console.log(userDetails.data)
        }).catch(function (err) {
           console.log(err);
        });
    }

    main();
```